# SOAP service to retieve scope detailse from WSO2IS

Tags: wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Is there SOAP service which returns the SCOPE from WSO2IS 5.5.0 ? I have bearer token generated using Oauth grant_type 'password'.  Using this token,  i need to retrieve set of scope associated with token.

I tried introespection RESTfull API, but its returning  ' Could not resolve host: application' error message .

Any suggestion please ?

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
{"error": "Invalid input"}

thansk a lot

Comment: paste the full CURL command here

Comment: C:\curl\cUrl>curl -k -u admin:admin -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -X POST --data 'token=a6998b8b-5fff-390d-abd6-b0c9170f3147' https://localhost:9443/oauth2/introspect                                                                  
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
{"error": "Invalid input"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : I missed the tailing 't' of the end point. Added that.
You are missing the protocol here.

```
curl -k -u admin:admin -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -X POST --data 'token=a6998b8b-5fff-390d-abd6-b0c9170f3147' https://localhost:9443/oauth2/introspect -v
```

You don't need to use the SOAP call therefore. In case you need it, here is the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/OAuth+Token+Validation+Using+SOAP+Service).

Comment: thanks for the response , apolgies for copy & paste mistake . I had this 'https' as protocol .  I tried again the same you curl command mentioned you above , reponded back with same error. as follows       C:\curl\cUrl>curl -k -u admin:admin -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -X POST --data 'token=a6998b8b-5fff-390d-abd6-b0c9170f3147' https://localhost:9443/oaut
h2/introspec
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application

Comment: https was removed automatically by site  after posting the comment  for some reason .

Comment: Also , SOAP call doesnt give me the SCOPE detailse .  I want to retrieve  list of SCOPE based on OAUTH token . thats the primary objective

Comment: I was missing the tailing 't' of the endpoint URL. Edited the answer. Give it a try.

Comment: C:\curl\cUrl>curl -k -u admin:admin -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -X POST --data 'token=a6998b8b-5fff-390d-abd6-b0c9170f3147' https://localhost:9443/oaut
h2/introspect -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* Could not resolve host: application
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.

Comment: WSO2IS version i am using is 5.5.0

Comment: Few things : 1. You are in Windows and CURL syntax might be different from it is of Linux.   2. When you type code/command snippets, wrap it with single quotes so that it wouldn't get misinterpreted.   3. The provided CURL works fine in Linux.

Comment: thanks a lot valuable input , will try to execute using POSTMAN

Comment: yes looks like issue is due to CURL command executing from windows env . I tried using POSTMAN its working fine